# Adjust download button to download two tables

Tags: r, shiny

The code below generates two tables, Table1 and Table2. When I press the `Download` button, I can download Table 1 only. This is working fine, but I would like to download Table 2 as well. Download the two tables together if possible.

I tried doing the following:  `writexl::write_xlsx(data_subset(), data_subset2(), path = file)`, but it didn't work. Can you help me?

I inserted an executable code below for you to test.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)
library(writexl)


Test <- structure(list(date2 = structure(c(18808, 18808, 18809, 18810
), class = "Date"), Category = c("FDE", "ABC", "FDE", "ABC"), 
coef = c(4, 1, 6, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                    br(),
                    
                    
                    tabPanel("",
                             fluidPage(
                               fluidRow(
                                 br(), br(),
                                 column(4,
                                        wellPanel(
                                            uiOutput("daterange"),
                                            downloadButton("dl", "Download")
                                             )),
                                 
                                 column(8,
                                        tabsetPanel(
                                          tabPanel("Table1", dataTableOutput('table')),
                                          tabPanel("Table2", dataTableOutput('table2'))
                
                                               )))
                                                       ))))

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  data <- reactive(Test)
  
  output$daterange <- renderUI({
    dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Period you want to see:",
                   start = min(data()$date2),
                   end   = max(data()$date2))
  })
  
  data_subset <- reactive({
    req(input$daterange1)
    days <- seq(input$daterange1[1], input$daterange1[2], by = 'day')
    subset(data(), date2 %in% days)
  })
 
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    data_subset()
  })
  
  
  data_subset2 <- reactive({
    req(input$daterange1)
    days <- seq(input$daterange1[1], input$daterange1[2], by = 'day')
    subset(data(), date2 %in% days)
  })
  
  output$table2 <- renderDataTable({
    data_subset2()
  })
  
  output$dl <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { "data.xlsx"},
    content = function(file) {
      writexl::write_xlsx(data_subset(), path = file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I haven't used the writexl package. But the openxlsx package allows you to add multiple data frames to an excel workbook as individual tabs. So that package might be worth looking at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)
library(writexl)

Test <- structure(list(date2 = structure(c(18808, 18808, 18809, 18810
), class = "Date"), Category = c("FDE", "ABC", "FDE", "ABC"), 
coef = c(4, 1, 6, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                    br(),
                    
                    
                    tabPanel("",
                             fluidPage(
                               fluidRow(
                                 br(), br(),
                                 column(4,
                                        wellPanel(
                                          uiOutput("daterange"),
                                          downloadButton("dl", "Download")
                                        )),
                                 
                                 column(8,
                                        tabsetPanel(
                                          tabPanel("Table1", dataTableOutput('table')),
                                          tabPanel("Table2", dataTableOutput('table2'))
                                          
                                        )))
                             ))))

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  data <- reactive(Test)
  
  output$daterange <- renderUI({
    dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Period you want to see:",
                   start = min(data()$date2),
                   end   = max(data()$date2))
  })
  
  data_subset <- reactive({
    req(input$daterange1)
    days <- seq(input$daterange1[1], input$daterange1[2], by = 'day')
    subset(data(), date2 %in% days)
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    data_subset()
  })
  
  
  data_subset2 <- reactive({
    req(input$daterange1)
    days <- seq(input$daterange1[1], input$daterange1[2], by = 'day')
    subset(data(), date2 %in% days)
  })
  
  output$table2 <- renderDataTable({
    data_subset2()
  })
  
  
  output$dl <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {"data.xlsx"},
    content = function(file) {
      #writexl::write_xlsx(df_list, path = file)
      tbl1<-data_subset()
      tbl2<-data_subset2()
      sheets <- mget(ls(pattern = "tbl")) # getting all objects in your environment with tbl in the name
      names(sheets) <- paste0("Table", seq_len(length(sheets))) # changing the names in your list
      writexl::write_xlsx(sheets, path = file) # saving the file
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: YBS, could take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70487675/how-to-insert-one-more-day-of-the-week-condition-into-shiny ?Thanks!