# Adjust the way to calculate the distance between two points in shiny code

Tags: r, google-maps, shiny

The shiny code below generates the route between two points, using the `googleway` function. Note that in addition, the distance between the two points is calculated, but this is the Euclidean distance and not the real distance using the `googleway` functions. The correct way to calculate the distance is by doing the following:

```
test<-google_directions(origin = c(-24.872139, -50.038787), destination = c(-24.9062992895515, -50.0125745903862), mode = "driving", alternatives = TRUE)

Distance<-sum(as.numeric(direction_steps(test)$distance$value)) 
[1] 6153
```

However, I would like this form of calculation in the shiny code below, in order to calculate the route properly. Therefore, can you help me adjust the code in shiny?

**Code in Shiny**

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(geosphere)
library(shinythemes)
library(googleway)

set_key( "YOUR_API_KEY")

k=3

function.cl<-function(df,k,Filter1,Filter2){
  
 df<-structure(list(Properties = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), Latitude = c(-23.8, 
 -23.8, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.4, -23.5), Longitude = c(-49.6, 
  -49.3, -49.4, -49.8, -49.6, -49.4, -49.2), 
  cluster = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L,3L)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
  

  df1<-structure(list(Latitude = c(-23.8666666666667, -23.85, -23.45
  ), Longitude = c(-49.6666666666667, -49.35, -49.3), cluster = c(1, 
  2, 3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
  
 
  #specific cluster and specific propertie
  df_spec_clust <- df1[df1$cluster == Filter1,]
  df_spec_prop<-df[df$Properties==Filter2,]
  
  #Table to join
  data_table <- df[order(df$cluster, as.numeric(df$Properties)),]
  data_table_1 <- aggregate(. ~ cluster, df[,c("cluster","Properties")], toString)
  

  # Map for route
  if(nrow(df_spec_clust>0) & nrow(df_spec_prop>0)) {
  df2<-google_directions(origin = df_spec_clust[,1:2], 
   destination = df_spec_prop[,2:3], mode = "driving")
          
    df_routes <- data.frame(polyline = direction_polyline(df2))
            
    m1<-google_map() %>%
      add_polylines(data = df_routes, polyline = "polyline")
    
    plot1<-m1 
  } else {
    plot1 <- NULL
  }
  
  
  DISTANCE<- merge(df,df1,by = c("cluster"), suffixes = c("_df","_df1"))
  
  (DISTANCE$distance <- purrr::pmap_dbl(.l = list(DISTANCE$Longitude_df,
                                                    DISTANCE$Latitude_df,
                                                    DISTANCE$Longitude_df1,
                                                    DISTANCE$Latitude_df1),
                                          .f = ~distm(c(..1,..2),c(..3,..4))))
  
  

  return(list(
    "Plot1" = plot1,
    "DIST" = DISTANCE,
    "Data" = data_table_1,
    "Data1" = data_table
  ))
}

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
             "Cl", 
             tabPanel("Solution",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          
                          selectInput("Filter1", label = h4("Select just one cluster to show"),""),
                          selectInput("Filter2",label=h4("Select the cluster property designated above"),""),
                          h4("The distance is:"),
                          textOutput("dist"),
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          tabsetPanel(      
                            tabPanel("Gmaps", (google_mapOutput("Gmaps",width = "95%", height = "600")))
                        
                      ))))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  Modelcl<-reactive({
    function.cl(df,k,input$Filter1,input$Filter2)
  })
  

  output$Gmaps <- renderGoogle_map({
    Modelcl()[[1]]
  })
  
  observeEvent(k, {
    abc <- req(Modelcl()$Data)
    updateSelectInput(session,'Filter1',
                      choices=sort(unique(abc$cluster)))
  }) 
  
  observeEvent(c(k,input$Filter1),{
    abc <- req(Modelcl()$Data1) %>% filter(cluster == as.numeric(input$Filter1))
    updateSelectInput(session,'Filter2',
                      choices=sort(unique(abc$Properties)))})
  
  output$dist <- renderText({
    DIST <- data.frame(Modelcl()[[2]])
    DIST$distance[DIST$cluster == input$Filter1 & DIST$Properties == input$Filter2]
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: I've removed the API key from the post for security and privacy concerns. Please don't share private API keys on public sites, and make sure you restrict them as per https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first simplify calculation of euclidian distance : `purrr::map` isn't needed here as the calculation is only between two points.

Then, road distance calculation is straight forward with the code you provided :

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(geosphere)
library(shinythemes)
library(googleway)

set_key( "YOUR_API_KEY")

k=3

function.cl<-function(Filter1,Filter2){
  
  df<-structure(list(Properties = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), Latitude = c(-23.8, 
                                                                       -23.8, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.4, -23.5), Longitude = c(-49.6, 
                                                                                                                                -49.3, -49.4, -49.8, -49.6, -49.4, -49.2), 
                     cluster = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L,3L)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
  
  
  df1<-structure(list(Latitude = c(-23.8666666666667, -23.85, -23.45
  ), Longitude = c(-49.6666666666667, -49.35, -49.3), cluster = c(1, 
                                                                  2, 3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
  
  
  #specific cluster and specific propertie
  df_spec_clust <- df1[df1$cluster == Filter1,]
  df_spec_prop<-df[df$Properties==Filter2,]
  
  #Table to join
  data_table <- df[order(df$cluster, as.numeric(df$Properties)),]
  data_table_1 <- aggregate(. ~ cluster, df[,c("cluster","Properties")], toString)
  
  
  # Map for route
  if(nrow(df_spec_clust>0) & nrow(df_spec_prop>0)) {
    df2<-google_directions(origin = df_spec_clust[,1:2], 
                           destination = df_spec_prop[,2:3], mode = "driving")
    
    df_routes <- data.frame(polyline = direction_polyline(df2))
    
    m1<-google_map() %>%
      add_polylines(data = df_routes, polyline = "polyline")
    
    plot1<-m1 
    # Euclidian distance
    distance_road <- sum(as.numeric(direction_steps(df2)$distance$value)) 
    # Road distance
    distance_straight <- distm(df_spec_clust[,2:1],df_spec_prop[,3:2])
  } else {
    plot1 <- NULL
    distance_road <- NA
    distance_straight <- NA
  }
  

  # Not needed?
  DISTANCE<- merge(df,df1,by = c("cluster"), suffixes = c("_df","_df1"))
  
  (DISTANCE$distance <- purrr::pmap_dbl(.l = list(DISTANCE$Longitude_df,
                                                  DISTANCE$Latitude_df,
                                                  DISTANCE$Longitude_df1,
                                                  DISTANCE$Latitude_df1),
                                        .f = ~distm(c(..1,..2),c(..3,..4))))
  
  
  
  return(list(
    "Plot1" = plot1,
    "DIST" = DISTANCE,
    "distance_road" = distance_road,
    "distance_straight" = distance_straight,
    "Data" = data_table_1,
    "Data1" = data_table
  ))
}

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
             "Cl", 
             tabPanel("Solution",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          
                          selectInput("Filter1", label = h4("Select just one cluster to show"),""),
                          selectInput("Filter2",label=h4("Select the cluster property designated above"),""),
                          h4("The distance is:"),
                          textOutput("dist"),
                          textOutput("distance_straight"),
                          textOutput("distance_road")
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          tabsetPanel(      
                            tabPanel("Gmaps", (google_mapOutput("Gmaps",width = "95%", height = "600")))
                            
                          ))))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  Modelcl<-reactive({
    function.cl(input$Filter1,input$Filter2)
  })
  
  
  output$Gmaps <- renderGoogle_map({
    Modelcl()[[1]]
  })
  
  observeEvent(k, {
    abc <- req(Modelcl()$Data)
    updateSelectInput(session,'Filter1',
                      choices=sort(unique(abc$cluster)))
  }) 
  
  observeEvent(c(k,input$Filter1),{
    abc <- req(Modelcl()$Data1) %>% filter(cluster == as.numeric(input$Filter1))
    updateSelectInput(session,'Filter2',
                      choices=sort(unique(abc$Properties)))})
  
  # Original calculation
  output$dist <- renderText({
    DIST <- data.frame(Modelcl()[[2]])
    paste0("Original distance calculation: ",round(DIST$distance[DIST$cluster == input$Filter1 & DIST$Properties == input$Filter2])," meters")
  })
  
  # Simplified version
  output$distance_straight <- renderText({
    paste0("Simplified distance calculation: ",round(Modelcl()$distance_straight)," meters")
  })
  
  output$distance_road <- renderText({
    paste0("Road distance calculation: ",Modelcl()$distance_road," meters")
    })
  

  
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Waldi that's right! I would like to kindly ask after placing the corresponding number, leave the word meters next to it, for example 14072 meters. Is there any way to adjust this?

Comment: See my edit : `paste0` allows any number of arguments, just added `" meters"` at the end.

Comment: Just one thing Waldi, see that in this example, with each property change via `selectInput`, the corresponding map is updated. However, I have an example where the graph of a property is generated, but after I change the property via `selectInput`, the map does not update, it only generates once. It's the same code I entered in this example. Where do you think the error could be if it is? Distance generates correctly with each property change, only the map that doesn't update generates the map for the first property only.

Comment: Perhaps better to post a specific question on the new reproducible example you have, difficult to tell without seing the code.

Comment: Please remove the API key in your code for security and privacy concerns.